# tail file - the file has become inaccessible and then has appeared

Tags: linux, django, tail

When I'm running django log and I sometimes get the following messages:

```
tail: `logs/debug.log' has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
tail: `logs/debug.log' has appeared;  following end of new file
```

Anyone know what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tail tries to access the *`logs/debug.log'* file while log rotation happens.

Logrotate rotates the file to *debug.log.0* or similar. New *`logs/debug.log'* file is created when there is something new to log into that file. This behavior leaves little window for for tail to access this file, discover that the file is missing and report it to you.

Review Django log rotation settings if this message annoys you too much.